# lecturer.tex and xetex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf, presentations, slideshow

I am experimenting with lighter-weight alternatives to beamer, and found `lecturer.tex` interesting. However, it depends on PDF-specific features, thus it compiles under `pdftex`. If I try to use `xetex` I immediately get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \pdfminorversion
                     5
```

then

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/lecturer/ltr-job.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
\yax@job@def .../\the \day /\the \year }}\pdfinfo
                                                  {\ltr@ifattribute job:pdfa...
```

etc.

Any chance to make this work with `xetex` ?

Comment: There are 108 occurences of `\pdf...` in the `lecturer` sources.  It would involve quite some effort to make these engine agnostic.

Comment: Certainly there is a _chance_ in the sense the things done using pdfTeX-specific primitives can all be done using different code that will work with XeTeX. I wonder though if that is a bit 'too broad' for the format here: whilst there are only a few places to change, the conceptual work is 'set up an entire driver-dependent concept in `lecturer`', which is probably too big a job.

Comment: @campa It's all doable but would need a structural re-write (to have driver-independent interfaces rather than direct primitive use).

Comment: BTW, depending on what you are aiming for it's quite doable to simply start from an `article` or similar and customise that.

Comment: There exists this simple glue for PDF literals `\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}`.  (However, this disregards `\pdfliteral direct`). I guess, that other primitves can be mapped in a similar way.

Comment: to be fair, I really like its simplicity and could do without the transition/uncover effects. Do you guys know of any similar deck engine minus the pdf-specific parts ? :-)

Comment: with `input luatex85.sty` as first line in the example file `LecturerDemo-BeamerCambridgeUS.tex` I can run that document with `luatex LecturerDemo-BeamerCambridgeUS`.